# What is the Hochberg–Armstrong Objection to Extreme Resemblance Nominalism?

Tags: metaphysics

I am reading the following text which I don't understand. Could someone help me understand this material? It is chapter 4 of Koons' Metaphysics Fundamentals book. Here's the following text:

"There is a further difficulty for Extreme Resemblance Nominalism, raised by both Herbert Hochberg (1999) and David M. Armstrong (2004). The Extreme Resemblance Nominalist, according to Hochberg and Armstrong, must say that one fact can be the truthmaker for distinct propositions, propositions that seem to require different states of the world to be true. Consider, for example:

(5) Particulars p1 and p2 are exactly similar, and (6) p1 and p2 are distinct particulars.

The Extreme Resemblance Nominalist must say that it's just the existence of p1 and p2 that make both (5) and (6) true. Indeed, if Extreme Resemblance Nominalism is true, the truth of (5) and (6) must be grounded in just the existence of p1 and p2. The pair {p1, p2} makes both (5) and (6) true. The Realist, on the other hand, can say that while that pair makes (6) true, (5) is made true by the fact that p1 and p2 share some one universal.

But what is the objection? The objection is that (5) and (6) seem to require different things of the world, and this is made clear by the fact that (6) could be true even if (5) were not. For p1 and p2 might have existed and been distinct, without being exactly similar. This is, at the very least, uncomfortable for the Extreme Resemblance Nominalist, since in such a case the truthmaker for (6), namely the pair {p1, p2}, would still exist! But further, and more troublingly, the relations expressed to hold between these two particulars by (5) and (6) are distinct. (5) says that p1 and p2 stand in a relation of similarity, while (6) says they stand in a relation of distinctness. These two relations have different extensions, not just possibly but actually. Given that these two relations are distinct, it is natural to require separate truthmakers.

Suppose that the Resemblance Nominalist accepts this requirement for different truthmakers where there are different relations. She can then postulate that there is a particular relation of resemblance that holds between p1 and p2, and insist that this particular resemblance relation is the truthmaker for (5), whereas the pair is the truthmaker for (6). The problem here, as Bertrand Russell (1959) emphasized, is that the Extreme Resemblance Nominalist thereby takes on an infinite regress. For one must ask what makes this particular relation a resemblance relation. The answer, of course, has to be that it resembles other such particular resemblance relations. But these relations resemble as well, and so we will need further resemblance relations to ground the fact that the resemblance relations are resemblance relations. And these relations doing that bit of explaining will need further resemblance relations to make them resemblance relations. And so on. This regress is vicious, since each new set of resemblance."

Answer (score 1):

As you probably know:

- **Nominalism** about universals is the idea that we don't need to posit universals to explain why a single predicate (like 'red') can apply to distinct things (like this ruby and that apple). Different versions of nominalism tell different stories about what we should say instead.
- According to **Resemblance Nominalism**, the reason why a single predicate can apply to distinct things is the fact the things resemble one another. Here, resemblance has to be understood as a primitive metaphysical relation, not explicable in terms of anything else.
- The label **Extreme Resemblance Nominalism** isn't used terribly often, but it seems to denote a version of Resemblance Nominalism according to which nothing exists except the distinct concrete things themselves. In particular, there is no third object which is the resemblance between the two things.

So, Hochberg and Armstrong are raising a problem for this last view. The argument goes like this.

1. Suppose that p1 and p2 are two exactly similar (but numerically distinct) objects.
2. According to ERN, the state of affairs that explains why p1 and p2 are similar -- that is, the *truthmaker* for the claim that p1 and p2 are similar -- is just the existence of p1 and p2. (It can't be, say, the existence of a resemblance between p1 and p2, since ERN denies the existence of resemblances.)
3. However, the state of affairs that explains why p1 and p2 are distinct objects is *also* the existence of p1 and p2.
4. The statements "p1 and p2 are exactly similar" and "p1 and p2 are numerically distinct" clearly make different claims about the world and have different truth conditions. (For example, the first statement could easily be false while the second was true.)
5. In general, if two statements make different claims and have different truth conditions, then one and the same state of affairs can't explain why both are true.
6. So it can't be that the mere existence of p1 and p2 explains the truth of both of the above statements.
7. This contradicts ERN, so ERN must be false.

It takes a lot of verbiage to express precisely, but the basic idea is pretty simple. The objection is that ERN posits a very small amount of metaphysical structure to do an outsized amount of truthmaking work, and it seems to fail at that job.

There's some further ideology behind some of these premises, e.g., various assumptions about what truthmakers are and how they work. And then the last part of the passage considers a possible reply by a defender of ERN and a Russellian argument against that reply. But that part is probably a bit more straightforward.